# Why doesn't gnu make's "override" pass through to sub-makes?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***Note:** This question was originally posted as a rant by a now-deleted user, but there was a valid question behind the rant; this is my attempt to provide an answer.*

Given the Makefile:

```make
ifeq "$(MAKELEVEL)" "0"

# Override the command-line specification of "foo".
override foo=replaced
export foo

all::
    @echo outer: foo is "$(foo)"
    @$(MAKE)

else

# Variable 'foo' was "exported" from the top-level Makefile.
all::
    @echo inner: foo is "$(foo)"

endif
```

The expectation is that `export foo` will cause make to export the value defined in the `override` declaration. But it doesn't:

```
$ make -s foo=original
outer: foo is replaced
inner: foo is original
```

Comment: @TobySpeight: Thanks. I even checked the supposedly authoritative list at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109 and there was no `lang-make` listed, but it's cool that it is there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The expectation is probably reasonable, but it turns out that this is not the way Gnu make works. It could well be that the `make` documentation could be improved to clarify the process, but the hints all seem to be there.

#### How variables get their values

A variable can be [set by the programmer](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Values.html) in three ways:

- On the command line with a `var=value` command-line argument
- Explicitly in the make file
- From the environment

The above list is the normal priority order; the first definition found in the list "wins". However, you can use the [`override` directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html) to swap the priorities of the first two methods. (You can also use the `-e` flag to make to swap the priorities of the last two methods. The `-e` flag is required by Posix, but its use is discouraged and it does not interact will with `override`.)

#### How variables are passed to sub-makes

`make` is very similar to a shell in that the environment is used to pass variable values. If a variable is marked as *exported*, then its value is placed into the environment for any processes initiated by make, including sub-makes. As with the shell, a variable is marked as exported if its definition came from the environment or if it is explicitly marked as exported with the `export` directive. Variables are also exported if they were set on the command line.

However, there is another mechanism by which variables on the command-line are passed to subprocesses: the [`MAKEFLAGS` exported variable.](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html). `MAKEFLAGS` contains (most) command-line options as well as all of the command-line variable overrides. If make finds `MAKEFLAGS` in the environment, it merges the settings in that variable with the ones actually specified on its command line. That means that command-line variable settings in a make will also take priority in a sub-make.

Since command-line variable settings are passed through the `MAKEFLAGS` variable, they are not subject to any changes in the makefile. A makefile can `unexport` or `override` a variable set on the command-line, but that will only affect the value (or presence) of the variable in the environment; it does not remove or change the value from `MAKEFLAGS`.

#### Resolution

So if the intent is to override (or modify) a command-line variable both in the make itself and in the environment of sub-makes, it is necessary to use both an override and an explicit modification of `MAKEFLAGS`. (As explained in the make manual, `MAKEFLAGS` is actually recursively composed using the `MAKEOVERRIDES` variable, so we actually modify that variable.)

```make
ifeq "$(MAKELEVEL)" "0"

# Override the command-line specification of "foo".
override foo=replaced
MAKEOVERRIDES += foo=replaced

all::
    @echo outer: foo is "$(foo)"
    @$(MAKE) -s

else

# Variable 'foo' was "exported" from the top-level Makefile.
all::
    @echo inner: foo is "$(foo)"

endif
```

And now we get the expected result:

```
$ make -s foo=original
outer: foo is replaced
inner: foo is replaced
```

#### Real-life application: dealing with whitespace

The primary intention of overrides is to allow the makefile to append words to a variable possibly provided on the command line. The example provided in the gnu make manual is insisting that `CFLAGS` always includes the `-g` flag, even if it were specified on the `make` command line:

```
override CFLAGS += -g
```

Passing the append through to a sub-make needs a little caution; in particular, the obvious:

```
MAKEOVERRIDES += CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS)  # Don't do this
```

won't work because the whitespace inside the `CFLAGS` variable will not be escaped when it is added to `MAKEFLAGS`; the result will be that `MAKEFLAGS` will look something like this:

```
-- CFLAGS=-O3 CFLAGS=-O3 -g
```

instead of the desired

```
-- CFLAGS=-O3 CFLAGS=-O3\ -g
```

If the value assigned to `CFLAGS` on the command line included whitespace, the whitespace is escaped in `MAKEFLAGS`. The particular escaping mechanism used is not documented, and Posix only requires that there be some mechanism; apparently, Gnu make uses backslash. It would be possible to manually backslash escape the whitespace, resulting in something like this:

```
# Don't do this either
MAKEOVERRIDES += CFLAGS=$(subst $(space),\ ,$(CFLAGS))
```

(The definition and use of `space` is based on an [example in the gnu make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Syntax-of-Functions.html).)

But it is actually easier to just use an append assignment in `MAKEOVERRIDES`, which is undocumented but appears to work. It works on the command line, too.

```
override         CFLAGS+=-g
MAKEOVERRIDES += CFLAGS+=-g
```

**Important Note as of make v4.1**: A bit of testing revealed that the above stanza will only work if `CFLAGS` (or some other variable) is actually set on the command-line. I reported this bug as [Savannah issue 46013](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=46013), with a very simple fix in the bug report. In the meantime, if you really want to do this, use the following workaround:

```
override         CFLAGS+=-g
MAKEOVERRIDES += CFLAGS+=-g

# This line is necessary in case there were no command-line overrides.
# In effect, it produces a command-line override, although that value
# will not be passed on to sub-makes.
MAKEFLAGS     += dummy=dummy
```

**Update May 19, 2019**: Today I was informed that a fix for the bug referenced above has been committed, so it should be fixed in the next gmake release.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to point out that your suggestion to add to `MAKEOVERRIDES`, is ***dangerous!***

And ***SHOULD NEVER BE DONE!!***

You simply turn a recursive variable into a simple one, you will ***always*** get false results, if recursive expansion is done.

I can not believe that you got up-voted for this clearly wrong "suggestion".

And note this:

- You can not even fix it with a quoted assignment, like `MAKEOVERRIDES += foo=$$(bar)`!!!

But, let me return to the main point of your post.

And, with which, I couldn't disagree more.

One simple example would be, if you run the very same makefile, that you have:

***This one is copied verbatim, from your post:***

```make
ifeq "$(MAKELEVEL)" "0"

# Override the command-line specification of "foo".
override foo=replaced
export foo

all::
    @echo outer: foo is "$(foo)"
    @$(MAKE) -s

else

# Variable 'foo' was "exported" from the top-level Makefile.
all::
    @echo inner: foo is "$(foo)"

endif
```

***And running in any modern version, 4.0 and up:***

```console
# Sub-make does NOT get the value from the root-Make's command-line.
# Instead, it "inherits" the value from the root-Make's definition in the Makefile.
$ make -s foo=original -e
outer: foo is replaced
inner: foo is replaced
```

Now, given your assertion above:

> However, there is another mechanism by which variables on the command-line are passed to subprocesses: the [`MAKEFLAGS` exported variable.][3]. `MAKEFLAGS` contains (most) command-line options as well as all of the command-line variable overrides. If make finds `MAKEFLAGS` in the environment, it merges the settings in that variable with the ones actually specified on its command line. That means that command-line variable settings in a make will also take priority in a sub-make.
>
> Since command-line variable settings are passed through the `MAKEFLAGS` variable, they are not subject to any changes in the makefile. A makefile can `unexport` or `override` a variable set on the command-line, but that will only affect the value (or presence) of the variable in the environment; it does not remove or change the value from `MAKEFLAGS`.

You should get:

```
outer: foo is replaced
inner: foo is original
```

In other words, we should get for the sub-make, the value defined on the command-line (`original`)!

Because, you said yourself:

> A makefile ***can't*** `unexport` or `override` a variable set on the command-line.

So, here, when we empower the environment over the makefile, which means that the makefile has less "power" in the total scheme of things. Right?

Sure, for such a case, you assertion will hold even stronger.

Comment: For what it's worth: The curious behaviour of the -e flag mentioned in the second half of this non-answer is indeed a bug, a regression from 3.8, and I filed it as savannah/46012. It doesn't strike me as particularly important since the -e option should pretty well never be used. And it has absolutely nothing to do with the question or accepted answer.

Comment: The dramatic warning about changing recursively-expanded variables into simply-expanded variables would make more sense if it were not for the "# Don't do this" comment; I probably should add a similar comment to the rather more extravagant (and also non-recommended) solution using `subst`. In fact, it *is* possible to pass a recursive expansion through `MAKEOVERRIDES` but you need to take into account both the need to escape both the value and the string used to create that value. The result is that you need to write `MAKEOVERRIDES += foo=$$$$(bar)`.

Comment: A makefile **can** override a variable set on the command line. According to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html), `If a variable has been set with a command argument (see `[Overriding Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html#Overriding)`), then ordinary assignments in the makefile are ignored. If you want to set the variable in the makefile even though it was set with a command argument, you can use an override directive`